# Open Vim help file directly from terminal

Tags: help-system

We can get help on Vim functions by typing the following from within Vim.

```
:help somecommand
```

For example, the following sends us to the help text for the unmap functionality.:

```
:help unmap
```

Is there any way to get Vim help directly in the terminal?
If I could put that functionality into a function, called say, vimhelp, I could then run from the terminal:

```
vimhelp unmap
```

And I could then open that text in Vim, like a normal file. Then I can use all the functionality I have come up with for all file working.

The question is now answered but for documentation purposes I would like to provide here the current state of the solution.

```
emanvim(){
    if [ -z "${1}" ]; then
        printf "Please provide Vim help topic.\n";
        return;
        fi  

    vim -i NONE -c "set bt=help|help $1" -- /tmp/dummy;
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more likely a Shell-scripting question. You could define the following function in your .bashrc:

```bash
vimhelp() {
    if [ -n "$1" ]; then
      vim -i NONE -c "set bt=help|help $1" -c 'nnoremap q :q!<cr>'
    else
      echo "please give help-topic to jump to"
    fi
  }
```

after resourcing your `.bashrc` file, you can use the command `vimhelp unmap` to directly jump to that in your vim editor.

Comment: I there any way to get rid of that error message in the beginning? It's like its expecting a filename.

Comment: Instead of `help xxx | only` you can do `set bt=help | help xxx`. Then the buffer #1 will be re-used ;-)

Comment: I don't get it. There is no `help xxx | only`. I tried the following, but same error.

Comment: vim -c "set bt=help | help $1" -c 'nnoremap q :q!<cr>'

Comment: @joh-jones what error?

Comment: I updated it just now but st ill get file not found error. Error detected while processing BufWinEnter Autocommands for "*":
E32: No file name

Comment: try to add `--clean` . I suspect some plugin comes into play. (I actually thought about adding `--clean` but that will prevent the function to load custom help files for installed plugins, so I did not do it)

Comment: I added clean, that stops the error but then it also stops loading the vimrc file. Which is very important.

Comment: you need to find out yourself, which plugins goes wrong here. Check `:verbose :au BufWinEnter` in your normal vim session

Comment: I added `-- /tmp/dummy` at the end. Just to have it load some dummy file and then it works. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

My very similar function is

```
vh() {
  vim +"help $*" +only
}
```

Based on some comments, I'll also mention that I have `nnoremap <buffer> q :quit` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/help.vim`.